# Using django admin site's multiple choice field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I guess most of you have paid attention to the admin site's multiple choice field:

[image]

I want the exact same widget to my MultipleChoiceField in my form. How is it possible to use that widget?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FilteredSelectMultiple`, for example writing a field into admin form

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class SomeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    some_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple('Field name', False)
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['your_model_fields', 'some_field']
```

It's works for `forms.MultipleChoiceField`.

The Django admin makes all the magic.